# how to insert rdf into virtuoso via jena?

Tags: jena, virtuoso

After i generate my rdf triple.I want to insert them into Virtuoso triple Store via Jena.

```
....
model.write(System.out,"RDF/XML");
....
url = "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111";
VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph (url, "dba", "dba");
Query sparql = QueryFactory.create("?????");
VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create (sparql, set);
vqe.exec();
```

How can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the [Virtuoso Jena Provider](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaProvider) includes a sample program [VirtuosoSPARQLExample8](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtJenaSPARQLExample8) demonstrating how to insert triples into a graph.